# Delete files older then X day.. BUT not by date modified

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have a config file for an .exe my workplace built where you can specify deleting of files (specifically retaining the last say 30 days files in my test here [logs and sql are fine]) and it even clears out sub folders. however it is deleting by date modified, so newer folders with some old remnents of data are getting the old remnents deleted.

```
Folder1:
File:   Modified:
File 1  2018/02/02
File 2  2010/05/06
File 3  2018/02/01

Folder 2:
File:   Modified:
File 1  2011/12/30
File 2  2006/01/16     
File 3  2018/02/02
```

Would leave:

```
Folder1:
File:   Modified:
File 1  2018/02/02
File 3  2018/02/01

Folder 2:
File:   Modified:    
File 3  2018/02/02
```

Is there anyway to change this so it retains the last 30 folders and contents,, deleting everything else?

This is the contents of the "cleaner".exe.config file I have:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <configuration>    <configSections>    </configSections>    <!-- Make sure that every new location has a name with an increasing number e.g clear 1 -->   
    <appSettings>
            <add key="connstring" value="Data Source=localhost;user id = *****;password = *****;Initial Catalog =Database;" />
            <add key="sqldays" value="180" />
            <add key="LogLocation" value="C:\File\Logs\Cleaner\" />
            <add key="clear" value="C:\Directory\Logs,90" />
            <add key="clear2" value="C:\Directory\CSV\Backup,30 " />
            <add key="fileExtensions" value=".txt,.csv,.log,.fmt,.hdr,.Log" />

            <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />   </appSettings> </configuration>
```

Comment: I don't see any `batch-file` code, so I am not sure how this pertains to that topic.

Comment: Sorry this is the config file, the batch file is an exe that I cant decompile as I cant even figure what it was coded in :/ likely VS2010 if it needs moving to a relevant forum or tag please help push it

Comment: A batch file cannot be an .exe, you don't compile batch files. There's some odd terminology going on here. You don't code in VS2010 either, you code in .Net or some other language and VS is your IDE and compiler.

Comment: That is likley completely correct, let me get a few things and Ill come back and update this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out it didnt matter about the modified date, the files just needed to 'be gone' so I added a few more directories to the config file and let it loose.

Example:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <configuration>    <configSections>    </configSections>    <!-- Make sure that every new location has a name with an increasing number e.g clear 1 -->   
    <appSettings>
            <add key="connstring" value="Data Source=localhost;user id = *****;password = *****;Initial Catalog =Database;" />
            <add key="sqldays" value="180" />
            <add key="LogLocation" value="C:\File\Logs\Cleaner\" />
            <add key="clear" value="C:\Directory\Logs,90" />
            <add key="clear2" value="C:\Directory\CSV\Backup,30 " />
            <add key="clear3"value="C:\Directory1\CSV\Backup,30 " /> 
            <add key="clear4" value="C:\Directory2\CSV\Backup,30 " />
            <add key="fileExtensions" value=".txt,.csv,.log,.fmt,.hdr,.Log" />

            <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />   </appSettings> </configuration>
```